# Number formatting not working with tabulate after printing text

Tags: python, floating-point, tabular

I'm writing this little program learning Python and I have faced a problem. I use tabulate with number formatting set to 5 numbers after separator, to make everything look nice, and it works, until I print text in the table. After text is printed (stating that you cannot divide by 0), formatting on that column seems to be gone.

The code is:

```
if skaiciuoti == True:
while bp <= bg:
    if (bp-a != 0):
        y = float(a / (bp - a))
        sk1.append(a)
        sk2.append(bp)
        sk3.append(y)
        bp = bp + bz
    elif (bp - a == 0):
        sk1.append(a)
        sk2.append(bp)
        sk3.append('Veiksmas negalimas (dalyba is 0)')
        bp = bp + bz

lentele = ['A reiksme', 'B reiksme', 'Y reiksme']
duomenys = zip(sk1, sk2, sk3)

print(tabulate (duomenys, headers=lentele, floatfmt=".5f", tablefmt="grid"))
```

Here are pictures to better illustrate my problem:

Working one

[image]

Broken one

[image]

I have tried formatting the number before appending it to the list, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to fix it myself. It was really not that hard, I just didn't think about it.

The solution that worked for me was to format number when appending it to the list (not before the list) like so

```
sk3.append(format(y, '.5f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`floatfmt` must be a list or a tuple, specifying one format for each column.

In your case, use e.g.:

```py
floatfmts = ('.5f', '.5f', '.5f')
print(tabulate (duomenys, headers=lentele, floatfmt=floatfmts, tablefmt="grid"))
```

(See e.g. https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/96/floatfmt-option-is-ignored-in-python3)